# PHP: how to create SWF (Ming or another solution)?

Tags: php, flash, pecl

I wish to create SWF (Flash) files with PHP but what is the best option for that nowadays? When I use Google I find all kinds of old pages about this subject, but not much is happening in this field lately, it seems....

Ming is no longer part of PHP 5.3,  and I can't figure out how to install it with PECL.
('pecl install ming' doesn't work... but neither does any pecl package I try, so I guess I do it all wrong...)

On http://pecl.php.net/package/ming it says the package has been superseded. My broken english tells me that means another package is now a better solution?  But which package then?

Is anybody actually using PHP to create SWF's or is this a bad idea anyway?

Comment: Usually PHP is just used to provide data (json, xml or other format) to flash applications instead of create them. Flash in itself is much more flexible than it used to be.

Comment: @Dylan The PECL page says ming moved to http://www.libming.org/

Comment: @MPD I saw that, but how do I install this package then... God, I hate linux... those stupid nerds that maintain those packages almost NEVER explain how to install/compile all this stuff... sorry no offense to nerds in general :)

Comment: dylan: You compile the libming source, and in the source tree somehwere there's a PHP subdirectory that'll build the library into a PHP module (a .so file) which you then load into PHP via a `dl()` call or an `extension=` directive in php.ini

Comment: I just never know how to compile anything in Linux... I need to unzip the package to a directory, but what directory?!  why is there never a simple 'install' command (preferably with some sort of GUI) in linux??!

Comment: in general (!) there are 3 really simple step to compile and install something in linux "./configure", "make", "make install"... in case of php extension you often need to call "phpize" before...
also also needed roughly 5 seconds to find the installation guide: https://github.com/libming/libming/blob/master/INSTALL

Comment: I DID IT! :)  also changed the php.ini.  I never compiled anything in linux before, so I'm kinda proud of myself now... but linux still sucks :)

Comment: I am getting error while using make command. The error is                                                    ming.c:4387:2: error: ‘struct _php_core_globals’ has no member named ‘safe_mode’
ming.c:4387:2: error: ‘CHECKUID_CHECK_FILE_AND_DIR’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what what the final swf should contain there are a few options:

- get libming running with your php installation
- [swfmill](http://swfmill.org/) - if you need fonts or simple images embedded into a swf (xml -> swf)
- mxmlc -  official free compiler from Adobe, takes ActionScript3 or Flex Input if you need more complex stuff (as3 / mxml -> swf)
- [Haxe](http://haxe.org) - similar approach as mxmlc, uses Haxe instead of ActionScript, very fast (hx -> swf)
- [Sam Haxe](http://www.mindless-labs.com/trac/samhaxe/) - similar to swfmill, written in Haxe (xml -> swf)

Answer (score 0):

There are number of utilities that can create SWFs from various source formats: flex, haxe, laszlo etc. You could generate such a source (e.g. xml) in php on the fly and invoke a compiler via exec to produce an swf.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to invoke the mxmlc compiler on the server, there's a command line for it. We did this recently for a project where we dynamically create a .swf file every time a user uploads a font, the .swf embeds that font and then the web service returns a path to the generated .swf which our parent .swf then loads in.